# need help adding a condition so my loop gives desired outcome using strings

Tags: c++, string, loops, parameters

My program takes numbers and formats them into international format. The program works except for 2 conditions. when inputted the format (817)555 7297 x23, the program should return a "-" when count == 4, but since that format is a "(" and not a digit, it skips the inserted dash. solutions? also for the same input, it is only suppose to display the first 10 digits yet it displays all the digits. I must be missing a parameter or something but I cant find it. any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
//This program takes in phone numbers
//and puts them in internation format
//By Remington Valadez
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string phonNumber; //to hold string
    string formattedNum = "+1-"; //to hold international format
    int count; //to hold count index
    int i; //to hold number index

    cout << "Please enter a phone number: "; //asks for phone number
    getline(cin, phonNumber); //use getline to get number and assign it to     phonNumber

    int numOfDigits = phonNumber.length(); //gets length of phone number

    for (i = 0, count = 0; count < 10; i++, count++) //runs a loop through the digits
    {
        if (phonNumber[i] <= '9' && phonNumber[i] >= '0') //reads only numbers
        {
            if (count == 4) //4th digit is -
            {
                formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
            else if (count == 7) //7th digit is -
            {
                formattedNum = formattedNum + "-";
            }
            formattedNum = formattedNum + phonNumber[i];
        }
    }
    numOfDigits = count;

    while (!(count >= 10)) {
        formattedNum = formattedNum + "x";
        count++;
    }
    cout << "The properly formatted number is " << formattedNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run the above program, one line at a time,what did you see?

Comment: `!(count >= 10)` is a pretty roundabout way of writing `count < 10`

Comment: Your example results in "+1-81755-57", the digits up to the tenth character. In your loop, `i` and `count` have the same value. If `count` is the number of digits, should you really increment it regardless of what the `i`:th character is?

Comment: Have you considered keeping a separate condition for when bracket close ')' is read? Why not use that as an indicator for when to put the dash instead of 4 digits?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your for loop, you are checking when to add a '-' based off how many characters you have checked instead of how many are in the number.

Something like this will work better.

```
 string formattedLocalNumber = "";
 for (int i = 0 ; i < phoneNumber.Length; i++, i++) //runs a loop through the digits
    {
        if (phoneNumber[i] <= '9' && phoneNumber[i] >= '0') //reads only numbers
        {
            formattedLocalNumber += phoneNumber[i];

            // Check the length of the string, if it is 6 or 3 add a '-'
            if (formattedLocalNumber.Length == 6 || formattedLocalNumber.Length == 3)
            {
                formattedLocalNumber += "-";
            }
        }
    }
    formattedNum += formattedLocalNumber;
```